# retrofit - Como enviar um JSON via POST

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Fala galera, estou usando o Retrofit 2 e nao estou conseguindo enviar JSON para o WS.

Tenho aqui minha classe que arruma o json do jeito que preciso:

**CustomGsonAdapter**

```
public class CustomGsonAdapter {
public static class UserAdapter implements JsonSerializer<NewObject> {
    public JsonElement serialize(NewObject user, Type typeOfSrc,
                                 JsonSerializationContext context) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonElement je = gson.toJsonTree(user);
        JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
        jo.add("order", je);
        return jo;
    }
}
}
```

Tenho também o meu API builder:

**ApiManager**

```
  HttpLoggingInterceptor logInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);


    okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(30000*6, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30000*6, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30000*6, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(logInterceptor)
            .build();



    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
            .registerTypeAdapter(NewObject.class, new CustomGsonAdapter.UserAdapter())
            .create();


    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(endpoint)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
```

Mas agora nao faço ideia de como tratar no meu *Request Interface*:

```
@POST("login")
    Call<BaseRequest> requestJson(@Body String json);
```

Minha dúvida é saber se estou no caminho certo e como faço agora pra finalizar e enviar o JSON para o WS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

Ao invés de enviar uma `String` mande um [RequestBody](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/RequestBody.html)!

```
@POST("login")
Call<BaseRequest> requestJson(@Body RequestBody object);
```

Exemplo para instanciar o `RequestBody`:

```
 final String json  =  "{\"description\": \"My description\"}";
 RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json);
```